# Use Amazon ElasticSearch Service as a web service for PHP application

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch

I don't know too much about Amazon services but I would like to ask you, if it is a good idea to use Amazon Elasticsearch Service as a webservice of an PHP application hosted somewhere out of Amazon services?

For example, I have an application running on managed server with limited options and I would like to start using elastic search in functions like searching products on web or something similar.

Is it a good idea? Thank you for your advices.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing is wrong with using [Amazon Elasticsearch Service](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/what-is-amazon-elasticsearch-service.html), but there are couple of points to note.

1) Although initial configuration is easy, you cant access `elasticsearch.yml` in case you want to make some changes since it is higher level service

2)We had problems with [dynamic scripting](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=683725&#683725) and [synonym file](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=679800), we could not even figure out how to put script file inside `config/scripts` folder. Once we wanted to add new field to our index but could not as `_close` operation was throwing error. Refer to this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33113365/cant-close-elasticsearch-index-on-aws) for more info.

We manually created our own cluster because of the above issues.

It is pretty new service from AWS as it was launched in October this year, It will become better in future, alternatively you could look at [found](https://www.elastic.co/found)

I hope this helps.

Comment: Same issues for me. It looks like this higher-level ES service from AWS is good enough for very simple use cases such as logging (since it provides also Kibana out of the box) but as soon as you need to tweak stuff and tinker, you're better off using some other service, such as Found, Heroku or just roll your own on EC2, DO or similar.

Comment: I completely  agree with you, as you said it is good for simple stuff but if you want to tweak some thing then you would be better off using some other service.